# three.js get camera position with orbit controls

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am using the three.js orbit controls and attempting to have a skybox follow the position of the camera.  Having searched the internet I've found no suitable answer.

My question is simple - how do I retrieve the coordinates of the camera when using orbit controls, the following doesn't work:

```
skybox.position.x = camera.position.x;  //Moving skybox with camera
skybox.position.z = camera.position.z;  //Moving skybox with camera
skybox.position.y = camera.position.y;  //Moving skybox with camera
```

The values of x and z coordinates are incorrect.  I have also tried:

```
orbit_controls.object.target
```

instead, but this results in similar incorrect behaviour with x and z returning incorrect values.

A seemingly obvious requirement of a control mechanism seems remarkably difficult to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having had no answer on SO I did some additional testing and I've discovered there is a need for a coordinate system transformation to retrieve the correct coordinates of the camera.

The following will retrieve the camera's current position in standard world (x,y,z) space and apply it to a skybox.

```
newZ = -(camera.position.x * Math.cos(5.49779)) - (camera.position.z * Math.sin(5.49779));
newX = (camera.position.x * Math.cos(0.78)) + (camera.position.z * Math.sin(0.78));

skybox.position.x = newX;   //Moving skybox with camera
skybox.position.z = newZ;   //Moving skybox with camera
skybox.position.y = camera.position.y;  //Moving skybox with camera
```

As I couldn't find this answer anywhere else, I hope this will be useful to other people, it solved my problem.

Comment: would you mind explaining how you got those numbers ? :) How did you identify they're needed ?

Answer (score 4):

This is a 2019 answer to a 2015 question:

`camera.position` is the local position of the camera. You can retrieve the global position by `camera.getWorldPosition(target)`, where `target` is a predefined `Vector3` object that will be set to the result.

By the way, you don't have to move the skybox with the camera. Instead, use the cube texture (or rendered cube) as scene.background.

Comment: Hey bro, are you sure that's how getWorldPosition works?? I'm trying to research something about how can I get the position of OrbitControls each time I make a move on it. Can you explain how to do that?

Comment: @MythVince The PerspectiveCamera extends Camera, which extends Object3D. Here is the definition of said method: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/src/core/Object3D.js#L495 As you can see, it needs to be called with a target vector object. I will update my answer to reflect this. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question, and what I did was include the following lines of code to the THREE.OrbitControls function, within the OrbitControls.js file.

```
THREE.OrbitControls = function ( object, domElement ) {

    .
    .
    .

  this.getPos = function() {
    pos = new THREE.Vector3();
    pos.copy( this.object.position );
    return  pos;
  };
  this.getCenter = function() {
    cent = new THREE.Vector3();
    cent.copy( this.center );
    return cent;
  };
    .
    .
    .
}
```

this.object it points to the camera Object you gave  when you created the Controls object, and this.center is a THREE.Vector3() initialized as (0,0,0) that defines where your camera is looking at.

And it worked perfectly. As you can see are two getter functions, one fetches the camera position, and the other fetches the center. Then I call it from my code like this:

```
//Create the controls object
var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls( this.camera, this.renderer.domElement);
//get the camera position whenever you want
var cameraPosition = controls.getPos();
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't know why, and this isn't a reflection on the method you have suggested because it could be something on my end, but using your exact code above I find it doesn't return correct coordinates.  Using the helper axis as a guide (as I did to confirm mine was correct) it doesn't seem to be returning the right values.